# Properties Added with Aspects Not in Generated JSON Schema

Tags: json.net, jsonschema, postsharp

I'm trying to generate JSON Schemas using Newtonsoft JSON Schema.  Regular properties added in my POCO class are added to the schema when it is generated.  I'm also using PostSharp Aspects to add properties, but none of those are added to the schema.

This is a Console application targeting .NET 4.7.2.

Here is my Console application:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JSchemaGenerator gen = new JSchemaGenerator();
        JSchema schema = gen.Generate(typeof(MyClass));
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\Temp\\TestSchema.json", schema.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is my aspect:

```
[PSerializable]
public class TestAspect : InstanceLevelAspect
{
    [IntroduceMember]
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string AspectProp { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my POCO:

```
[TestAspect]
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, here is the generated schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "MyProperty": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "MyProperty"
  ]
}
```

The `MyProperty` property is in the schema, but `AspectProp` - the property added by the aspect - is not.

When I open the exe in a decompiler, I can see that `AspectProp` is actually added to `MyClass`:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a problem with PostSharp or Newtonsoft JSON Schema or if I'm doing something wrong.  It seems like this should be possible.

**Edit 1: 20 May**
I split my solution out into separate projects - one for the Console app, one for the Aspect and one for `MyClass`.  After making sure I was referencing the generated `MyClass` DLL directly (i.e. not a project reference, I actually removed the project once `MyClass` was built) it did not make a difference.  `AspectProp` is still not in the schema.  Based on this and the serialization suggested below by @dbc, this leads me to believe it is a problem with the Newtonsoft schema generator

**Edit 2: 20 May**
Per Antonin's Answer below, I created a new ContractResolver:

```
public class AspectPropertyResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public AspectPropertyResolver()
    {
        SerializeCompilerGeneratedMembers = true;
    }
}
```

And then registered it in my app before calling `Generate`:

```
gen.ContractResolver = new AspectPropertyResolver();
```

Now my schema includes the aspect-generated property.

Comment: What happens if you serialize an instance of `MyClass` with an `AspectProp` set?

Comment: When I serialize MyClass to JSON using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer, AspectProp is there: {"MyProperty":3,"AspectProp":"zz"} with the values I set

Comment: Look at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.SerializeCompilerGeneratedMembers property.

Comment: Winner, winner, chicken dinner... @AntonínProcházka put that in as an Answer and I'll accept.  Thanks.

Comment: @TimTheEnchanter Great! Glad to help. Happy PostSharping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newtonsoft.Json has an opt-in feature to serialize compiler-generated properties. See `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.SerializeCompilerGeneratedMembers` property.